# ¿Cómo hacer para que funcione background geolocation con el teléfono bloqueado? - IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic, cordova, ionic-framework

llevo días intentando hacer que funcione el background geolocation con el teléfono bloqueado. ¿Es posible?, yo diría que si porque hay apps como Whatsapp que lo hacen. Gracias de antemano a quien me pueda echar una mano.

Comment: agrega la versión de ionic y cordova por favor. Y la versión de los plugins que estas usando

Comment: Es IONIC 5, y estoy utilizando el plugin: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Comment: Me refiero a esto:
ionic info
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.4.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.21.0
   npm    : 6.14.5
   OS     : Linux 4.15

cordova -v
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Comment: Cabe recalcar que yo uso nvm pues uso diferentes entornos de ionic. Genera esos comandos para verificar con que version estas trabajando por favor